# Gulp task to create page specific js files, concatenating common js files with page specific files

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

Assuming a directory structure like

- src/

  - scripts/

    - _common/

      - common.js
    - page1.js
    - page2.js

I want to create distinct files that concatenate common + page1 and a separate file for common + page2.

Output to look something like

- dist/

  - page1/

    - script.js
  - page2/

    - script.js

where script.js is each page's specific js concatenated to common.

I have something working on the sass side that creates the folders so really all I need to do is figure out how to get page specific files and drop them in a folder named for the original source file

```
return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
     .pipe(rename(function(file) {
        file.dirname = file.basename;
        file.basename = 'style';
        file.extname = '.css';
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the js:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const glob = require("glob");
const addSource = require("gulp-add-src");
const concat = require("gulp-concat");
const path = require("path");

// get an array of files
const files = glob.sync("./src/scripts/*.js");

gulp.task('default', function () {

  files.forEach(function (file) {

    return gulp.src(file)

          // append or prepend here (prepend to put common.js first)
      .pipe(addSource.prepend('./src/scripts/_common/common.js'))

      .pipe(concat("script.js"))

      .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/" +  path.basename(file, '.js')));
  });
});
```